# Template class argument for template class function syntax

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    T val;
    Foo(T p_val) : val(p_val) {}
    T sum(Foo<T> other) { return val + other.val; }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> f1(3);
    Foo<int> f2(5);
    std::cout << f1.sum(f2) << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `8` as expected.

If I change the member function signature to `T sum(Foo other)` (removing the `<T>`), it still prints `8`. In general does it matter whether I include that `<T>` or not? I'm using Visual C++ 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `template<...> class X`, the name `X` as a non-template refers to `X<...>`.

So that `<T>` is redundant there.  It is legal, but redundant.